# Chrome extension popup - button resizes incorrectly after clicking

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension with a popup (a popup is the HTML rendered when you click the short-cut to the extension, next to the omni-bar).

I have some standalone buttons and for some reason whenever I click them they do not return to their original view state. They continue to work (I can continue to click them), but they are very small. Not ideal.

Before Click:

[image]

After Click:

[image]

The HTML itself is simply:

```
<input type="button" id="search" value="Search" />
```

with is no enclosing form.

Any clues as to what could be causing this? The same happens with inputs of type "submit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a javascript somewhere that sets empty input value. Maybe your input id/class matches some other element you are cleaning.

Remove all javascript from the page and go from there adding it back part by part.

Comment: I hear you, but no, there 'aint no JS.

Comment: @Joel So you don't have anything in the popup html except this one button and it still does it? Which Chrome version do you have?

Comment: I need my eyes looking at. Yes, there was some rogue JS. Thanks for the pointer serg!

Answer (score 0):

You might have put some javascript that empties the value. Try replacing input buttons with
`<button></button>`
and see if it still happens.